# Remove outliers from the target column when an independent variable column has a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normal-distribution, outliers

I have a dataframe that looks as follow (click on the lick below):

```
df.head(10)
```

https://ibb.co/vqmrkXb

What I would like to do is to remove outliers from the target column (occupied_parking_spaces) when the value of the day column is equal to 6 for instance which refers to sunday (df[‘day’] == 6) using the normal distribution 68-95-99.7 rule.

I tried the following code :

```
df = df.mask((df['occupied_parking_spaces'] - df['occupied_parking_spaces'].mean()).abs() > 2 * df['occupied_parking_spaces'].std()).dropna()
```

This line of code removes outliers from the whole dataset no matter the independent variables but I only want to remove outliers from the occupied_parking_spacs column where the day value is equal to 6 for exemple.

What I can do is to create a different dataframe for which I will remove outliers:

```
sunday_df = df.loc[df['day'] == 0]

sunday_df = sunday_df.mask((sunday_df['occupied_parking_spaces'] - sunday_df['occupied_parking_spaces'].mean()).abs() > 2 * sunday_df['occupied_parking_spaces'].std()).dropna()
```

But by doing this I will get multiple dataframes for everday of the week that I will have to concatenate at the end, and this is something I do not want to do as there must be a way to do this inside the same dataframe.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: Dont post pictures of code/data, we cannot copy your picture. I see you have your data already in a Python IDE. Simply do `print(df.head(10))`, copy and paste that in your question instead of the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having defined some function to remove outliers, you could use `np.where` to apply it selectively:

```
import numpy as np
df = np.where(df['day'] == 0, 
        remove_outliers(df['occupied_parking_spaces']),
        df['occupied_parking_spaces']
     )
```

Comment: I tried this by first defining a function  'def outlier_removal(x):
    q_95 = x.quantile(0.95)
    q_5 = x.quantile(0.05)
    return (x>q_95) | (x<q_5)' and then I applied it to my dataframe 'import numpy as np
df = np.where(df['day'] == 0, 
        df['occupied_parking_spaces'].apply(outlier_removal),
        df['occupied_parking_spaces']
     )' but I got an error message saying (AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'quantile')

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong.  It shouldn't be an apply - whatever outlier function you have should take the whole series as its argument.  Try it now.

Comment: I tested the code again and it returns an array and not the dataframe with the outliers removed with that specific condition. What I would like is Something like this but without that arbitrary value of 1.96 but 2 sigmas. 'df1 = df[~df.groupby('Data').transform( lambda x: abs(x-x.mean()) > 1.96*x.std()).values]'

Comment: I have found the solution. 'df = df[~df.groupby('day').transform( lambda x: abs(x-x.mean()) > 2*x.std()).values]'